# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '130.4,120.6,110.9'

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code and I am getting the error 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: '130.4,120.6,110.9'' when I run this code. I am a newbie. Can anyone help me please

```
import numpy as np
input_delta = input("Enter your coordinate: ")
Delta_coordinates = float(input_delta)
a = np.zeros((3, 3), int)
np.fill_diagonal(a, 100)
rotation_matrix = np.matrix([[-0.8660, 0.8660, 0], [0.5, 0.5, -1], [1, 1, 1]])
delta_abc = a*Delta_coordinates
mul_inverse = np.linalg.inv(a)
print(mul_inverse)
car = rotation_matrix*mul_inverse
cartesian = car*delta_abc
print(cartesian)
```

Comment: can you plase post the full stack trace and also provide sample input, expected output

Comment: I take it `130.4,120.6,110.9` is what you're entering at the `input` statement?  `float` is only appropriate for converting a single value at a time.

Comment: Please provide input and output. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `float(input_delta)`, Python tries converting "input_delta" into a single float number. Since your string contains multiple values separated by commas, you could split the string into three parts and convert each part into a float, something like:

```
a = [float(x) for x in [input_delta.split(",")]]
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = '130.4,120.6,110.9'
>>> [float(x) for x in s.split(",")]
[130.4, 120.6, 110.9]
```